# Launching activity on receiving push notification (Like Skype/WhatsApp call)

Tags: android, push-notification, call, whatsapp, skype

How can I launch a CALL UI activity from background on receiving push notification? How does Apps like Skype and WhatsApp show call like UI? I want to launch an activity on receiving push notification, see image attached.

[This is what I want to display on receiving notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjm7i.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about the Call UI activity, its just a regular activity fully created by you. You have to catch the incoming message in the appropriate service depending on the way you are sending notifications, then launch your activity with startActivity() by using some context.

Comment: Perfect! I've tried but It only launches the activity if the app is running. Can you help me launch the activity even if the app is not running? Here's my code:

Comment: try adding some of these flags Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or check the logcat, maybe it says whats wrong